# jQuery Slidetoggle - force div open if closed?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery slideToggle to show/hide comments.  I need my function to always make sure the DIV is open after a comment post.  How do I do this?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "trackid="+trackid,
            url: "http://rt.jaxna.com/viewcomments.php",
            success: function(data)
                {   
                //  alert(data);
                     $(".userError").append(data);

                }
            });
            $(parent).slideToggle();
            $(parentNew).slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add

```
if($('#my_div').is(':hidden'))
{
    $('#my_div').slideDown();
}
```

Comment: They are currently set to display:none.  Will this still work?

Comment: Yep that's part of the pseudo-selector `:hidden`